# How to insert multiple records in loopback

Tags: loopback, fireloop

I have collection of records for a model. But there is no method available to insert into Mongo db in Fireloop.

Is there any method available ?

Comment: You can insert multiple documents as array of objects.for ref http://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#persistedmodel-create

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is, in you `models` create endpoint give an `array` instead of `object`

Example: in `Products` model

```
this.productApi.create(
  [
    {name: "Toy Car"},
    {name: "Purse"},
    {name: "Charger"}
  ]
).subscribe((res)=>console.log(res))
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, PersistedModel.create([data], callback)
As Arguments   Optional data argument. Can be either a single model instance or an array of instances.
Pass object
[image]
Pass Array
[image]

Hope this helps.